# session maximum size in FuelPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm using a session in mysql.
when it write string base64 encode image of 1MB, it is error.
this is not change session var.
but, string size 500KB is success.

mysql table column 'payload' is longtext. it is maximum 4GB.
I don't think there is any problem.

What do you think causes?

I am using nginx, mysql, php5.4, fuelphp.

```
//base64 text, 1MB.
$img = "......"; 

// not error, but no change session.
Session::set("img", $img);
```

thanks

Comment: I think that storing anything that size in a session is abusing sessions, and completely unnecessary

Comment: Just to make it clear: are you using the `db` session driver? For me "I'm using a session in mysql" means something completely different, so I'm not sure. If you're using the `cookie` driver, then it's too long for the HTTP headers. I also agree with @MarkBaker